# Backbone event don't trigger when click on child

Tags: events, backbone.js, triggers

I have a problem with backbone event.

```
// The DOM events //
events: {
    'click table.table-sorter th[data-column]' : 'sort'
},

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-column="name">name <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
        <th>description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

The event is well trigger when I click on the **th** but not on the **i**.

But if I use the on function of jQuery in the render view function it works:

```
$("table.table-sorter th[data-column]").click(function(){
    <i> is trigger 
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2Zzrh/, what are you doing that's different?

Comment: Wow, that's very strange.
I will continue to search why it does not work for me...
Thank you ;-)